# Custom ticks autoscaled when using imshow?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to change the value of the ticks on the x-axis an `imshow` plot using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def scale_xaxis(number):
    return(number+1001)

data = np.array([range(10),range(10,20)])
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(data,aspect='auto')
ax.autoscale(False)
xticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(scale_xaxis(xticks))
plt.savefig("test.png")
```

[Resulting image http://ubuntuone.com/2Y5ujtlEkEnrlTcVUxvWLU](http://ubuntuone.com/2Y5ujtlEkEnrlTcVUxvWLU)

However the x-ticks overlap and have "non-round" values. Is there some way for matplotlib to automatically do this? Either by using `set_ticklabels` or some other way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Also look into using `extent` [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow) to let `matplotlib` do all the thinking about how to put in the tick labels and add in an arbitrary shift:

```
data = np.array([range(10),range(10,20)])
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(data,aspect='auto',extent=[10000,10010,0,1])
```

If you definitely want do to it my hand, you might be better off setting the `formatter` and `locator` of the `axis`  to get what you want [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#module-matplotlib.ticker).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def scale_xaxis(number):
    return(number+1001)

def my_form(x,pos):
    return '%d'%scale_xaxis(x)

data = np.array([range(10),range(10,20)])
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(data,aspect='auto')
ax.autoscale(False)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(int(2)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(my_form))
```

The locator needs to be set to make sure that ticks don't get put at non-integer locations which are then forcible cast to integers by the formatter (which would leave them in the wrong place)

related questions:

[matplotlib: format axis offset-values to whole numbers or specific number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677368/matplotlib-format-axis-offset-values-to-whole-numbers-or-specific-number)

[removing leading 0 from matplotlib tick label formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555652/removing-leading-0-from-matplotlib-tick-label-formatting)

Comment: This works for the specific problem, and answers the question I asked (in retrospect I see that I phrased my question poorly). But it doesn't really solve the main problem I had: I need some way to make matplotlib to select the appropriate number of ticks.
For example if return(number+1001) was return(number+10001). How could I then make matplotlib automatically select the right number of ticks to avoid overlap?
Should I accept the answer and make a new question, or should I edit this question?

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this.

You can:

1. Pass in an array of ints instead of an array of floats
2. Pass in an array of formatted strings
3. Use a custom tick formatter

The last option is overkill for something this simple.

As an example of the first option, you'd change your `scale_xaxis` function to be something like this:

```
def scale_xaxis(numbers):
    return numbers.astype(int) + 1001
```

Note that what you're getting out of `ax.get_xticks` is a numpy array instead of a single value. Thus, we need to do `number.astype(int)` instead of `int(number)`.

Alternately, we could return a series of formatted strings. `set_xticklabels` actually expects a sequence of strings:

```
def scale_xaxis(numbers):
    return ['{:0.0f}'.format(item + 1001) for item in numbers]
```

Using a custom tick formatter is overkill here, so I'll leave it out for the moment. It's quite handy in the right situation, though.